# Trying to change the first character of every row in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series list1:

```
1      listId
95     LaBc.defGabc
97     Kasd.defGabc
99     aaSd.defGabc
101    Basd.defGabc
103    Lasd.defGabc
105    Lasd.defGabc
```

I want to `lower()` only the first character of every item so it looks like:

```
1      listId
95     laBc.defGabc
97     kasd.defGabc
99     aaSd.defGabc
101    basd.defGabc
103    lasd.defGabc
105    lasd.defGabc
```

I'm trying:

```
list1 = list1.map(str).str[0].lower()
```

but I get error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str[0].str.lower()+df['value'].str[1:]
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `list1.map(str).str[0]` is a Pandas series, and `series.lower()` doesn't work as you saw in the error. It should be `series.str.lower()` as other answers pointed out.

In this case, however, just a straight `.apply` here is fine, while is most likely faster than other `.str` methods. This is because you don't need to generate multiple intermediate series:

```
df['listId'] = df['listId'].apply(lambda x: x[0].lower() + x[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a short regex and a function:

```
df['listId'] = df['listId'].str.replace(r'^(.)', lambda m: m.group().lower(),
                                        regex=True)
```

Or splitting the string to handle the first character independently:

```
df['listId'] = df['listId'].str[:1].str.lower()+df['listId'].str[1:]
```

Output:

```
     1        listId
0   95  laBc.defGabc
1   97  kasd.defGabc
2   99  aaSd.defGabc
3  101  basd.defGabc
4  103  lasd.defGabc
5  105  lasd.defGabc
```

Comment: Can you explain what that first .replace is doing?

Comment: @Mitch of course, the `^(.)` regex is capturing the first character and then the function (lambda) converts it to lowercase.

Comment: is ```^(.)``` a defined regex code for first character? Are there others?

Comment: It's a construction with classical regex characters. `^` means "start of string", `(…)` is a capturing group, `.` means any character. So you're matching the first char and replace it with it's lowercase version. You actually don't really need the capturing group here `^.` would also work